# Devexpress winforms gridcontrol - Get id from selected row on both right and left click event

Tags: winforms, devexpress, gridcontrol

I am trying to learn Devexpress winforms gridcontrol in my software expertise course. I have not managed yet to get id from selected row both right and left click event. I want an event that triggered both right and left click and meanwhile I want to get selected row id (or first cell value.).
If I manage to get row id, I don't want to show id into row. But if not, I will show id into first cell and trying to get firs cell value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it by using `gridView_FocusedRowChanged`event  because `Left or Right click` will fire the event.

Here is a sample code to get `ID` from FocusedRow

```
private void gridView_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string ID = gridView.GetFocusedRowCellValue("ID").ToString();
}
```

Hope it's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Triple K's solution, here's how you can detect which mouse button was clicked in, say the Click event of the grid by casting "e" to DXMouseEventArgs:

```
private void gridView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((DXMouseEventArgs)e).Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        string ID = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("ID").ToString();

        MessageBox.Show("ID: " + ID);
    }
}
```